# What to do if you're a Luke in trouble

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

> My infix has 99 names.
>   My prefix is more.
>   My suffix comes after XI.
>   My whole is a dirty surname.

What to do if you're a Luke in trouble?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is

> CALLAHAN

My infix has 99 names.

> As Rand al'Thor said, this is **ALLAH**.

My prefix is more.

> What's more than 99? 100! Or, **C**.

My suffix comes after XI.

> **AN** does come after Xi in the name of a city in China.

My whole is a dirty surname.

> [Dirty Harry Callahan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066999/)

What to do if you're a Luke in trouble?

> A Luke should **call a Han**!

Comment: I'm on the same path, but I can't figure out how does the suffix relate.

Comment: For the suffix the rot13(Terrx yrggre Kv pbzrf evtug nsgre Ah (A)) but that seems to be the opposite of the hint...

Comment: It’s quite possible that it refers to Solo making the Kessel run in 12 parsecs.....but that’s a nifty stretch!

Comment: Actually it more likely refers to rot13(Kv'na, n pncvgny va Puvan)

Comment: Perhaps "Xi" refers to "Xi'an"?

Comment: My aversion to @LukeC.J.Currie's suggestion is that the XI is capitalized, suggesting its an initialism or referencing the roman numeral. But nothing better comes to mind.

Comment: the XI could be a reference to the Xī Hàn dynasty of China.

Comment: Xi'an (an comes after Xi)

Comment: Let's see how many people post the same comment...

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

*My infix has 99 names.*

> [This](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Islam) is GOD or ALLAH.

*My suffix comes after XI.*

> This is TWELVE or DOZEN.

Putting the above together, we seem to get a word that ends with

> GODOZEN.

I'm not sure about the prefix though ...